# How to connect InfluxDB to PowerBI and PowerQuery

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, influxdb

I am having a problem where my time series database cannot connect to PowerBI for querying.

I've tried the connector https://github.com/Synergetic-Engineering/odata-influxdb but ran into an issue where the database cannot be parsed by the connector.

Does anyone know of any other methods to connect PowerBI to InfluxDB?

Comment: Any news on this matter?